# Using MongoDB $arrayToObject using custom keys

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider the following document that is output of an aggregation pipeline:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "results" : [
  { "status" : "HOLD", "footage" : 43.01, "pieces" : 1 }, 
  { "status" : "ACCEPTED", "footage" : 80.90, "pieces" : 2 },
  { "status" : "REJECTED", "footage" : 40.00, "pieces" : 1 }
]}
```

I am trying to create custom keys that concatenate the status with the footage and piece fields resulting in:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "results" :
  {
    "HOLD_footage": 43.01,
    "HOLD_pieces":1,
    "ACCEPTED_footage": 80.90,
    "ACCEPTED_pieces": 2,
    "REJECTED_footage":40.00,
    "REJECTED_pieces":1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following:

1. use `$map` to build the k-v tuples with key you want(i.e. HOLD_footage...)
2. use `$concatArrays` to group back the arrays of k-v tuples
3. use `$objectToArray` to get back the array form you expected

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "results": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$results",
          "as": "r",
          "in": [
            {
              k: {
                $concat: [
                  "$$r.status",
                  "_footage"
                ]
              },
              v: "$$r.footage"
            },
            {
              k: {
                $concat: [
                  "$$r.status",
                  "_pieces"
                ]
              },
              v: "$$r.pieces"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "results": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$results",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "results": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$results"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rS7H5e5VD8K)